# How to eval string function and return value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a method in string like:

```
var str = "function evalTest(param){if(param)return '<div>hello</div>'}else return '<div>world</div>'"
```

I am replacing param like:

```
 var res = str.replace("param", "param=false");
```

Now if I do eval like:

```
var final = eval(res);
```

I am expecting final should contain result "world" because passed param = false.

How to achieve this result "world"?

Comment: This is very dangerous.  You should read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: *"I have a method in string like"* Whatever problem you're trying to solve by doing that, there's almost certainl a better way to solve it. You might consider posting a question about *that* problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First a caveat:** There's almost certainly a better solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve by having that function in a string.

**And another one:** Never `eval` code supplied by an end user except for that same end user. For instance, never let user A supply the code, then `eval` it in user B's browser. (Without user B knowing that you're doing that and expressly consenting to it.)

Really, almost any time you're reaching for `eval` (or its cousin `new Function`), it's worth stepping back to see if there's another approach you can use.

---

But answering the question asked:

`eval` is just creating the function. You don't have anything in that string that *calls* it.

Because `eval` works magically in the current scope, `eval`ing your string creates the function in the current scope. You could then call your function to get the result you're looking for:

```js
var str = "function evalTest(param){if(param){return '<div>hello</div>'}else {return '<div>world</div>'}}";
var res = str.replace("param", "param=false");
eval(res);
var final = evalTest();
console.log(final);
```

Note that I fixed a couple of syntax errors in the function's text (curly brace issues, mostly).

If you don't want the function defined in the current scope, you can modify the string to make it a function expression and call it immediately:

```js
var str = "function evalTest(param){if(param){return '<div>hello</div>'}else {return '<div>world</div>'}}";
var res = str.replace("param", "param=false");
var final = eval("(" + res + ")()");
console.log(final);
```